# Base class return reference to extended class type mismatch

Tags: typescript

I have a simplified version of a base class, which is supposed to be a node of a tree structure and holds a reference to it's parent.

```
class Node {
  parent: Node;

  setParent(a: Node) {
    this.parent = a;
  }

  getParent(): Node {
    return this.parent;
  }
}
```

Derived class adds a bit more functionality to the basic node

```
class NamedNode extends Node {
  name: string;

  setName(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

I create my small tree using derived class and store a reference to a parent in a child by calling `setParent`, and then retrieve the parent from a child by calling `getParent`.

```
const parent = new NamedNode();

const child = new NamedNode();
child.setParent(parent);

const parentOfChild = child.getParent();

parentOfChild.setName('foo');
```

When I make a call `setName` on a retrieved parent, even though it is an instance of `NamedNode`, TypeScript throws an error

> Property 'setName' does not exist on type 'Node'.

I can understand that, because method signature `getParent(): Node` explicitly defines that it returns only instance of `Node` and it does not have `setName` method in it.

My question is how to make `getParent` return an instance of `Node` so I would know that the return value will have the methods of a `Node`, but at the same time it should be open for extension so I would be able to call descendant methods on the returned value without TypeScript complaining. My goal is that every descendant node class will have the `Node` methods, and instances of these descendant classes then can be used in the base `Node` class as a `parent` reference. I would also like to avoid overriding `Node` methods in derived classes to update `Node` method signatures, because the whole point of inheritance method reuse will be gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` as a type meaning the type of the current class, so that in the derived class `parent` will be of the same type as the derived class:

```
export class Node {
    parent: this;

    setParent(a: this) {
        this.parent = a;
    }

    getParent(): this {
        return this.parent;
    }
}

class NamedNode extends Node {
    name: string;

    setName(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


const parent = new NamedNode();

const child = new NamedNode();
child.setParent(parent);

const parentOfChild = child.getParent();

parentOfChild.setName('foo');
```

This feature of the language is called polymorphic this, you can read more about it in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) or the [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910)

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I needed. A bit overwhelmed with all the features of TS and did not get to that point in the docs yet.